# Java как сделать авто ввод без нажатия Enter

Tags: java, ввод, автозапуск

Допустим:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exsperimental {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner R1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int one;

one = R1.nextInt();

System.out.print(one);
}
}
```

Как сделать чтобы после ввода однозначного числа, не нужно было нажимать enter?
Допустим я нажал 1 и программа сама сразу после нажатия "1" выполнила ввод.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой, к примеру https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook которая перехватывает нажатие клавиш, и, по идее мышки

Answer (score 0):

Не сразу понял вопрос, похожий вопрос уже задавали:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it

Comment: Как бы сказал Ипатьев, прежде чем ответить, желательно прочесть сам вопрос.